# MUI Autocomplete doesnt take Value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete with all user in it.
When a user clicks on a Button on a different site it gets redirected to this site and i get the id of the user with a fetch.
Now i want that the User with the Corresponding ID is automaticly selected.
But when i try it nothing gets selected.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-water-tv27nn?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a warning in the console telling

> MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.

That means your value changes from `undefined` to something else. And that prevents it from working correctly. Your initial value should be `null`, not `undefined`

```
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);
```

Then it will work as expected

And also don't update the state directly in the body of the component, it will push to that state on each render

```
userArray.push({ id: "s", fullName: "d" });  // never update state directly!
```